# Connect arrow key to method when using pyqt5 QAbstractTableModel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to design a table widget in pyqt that gets the value in the first column of a row when navigating the table with the arrow keys. I'm able to do that using clicked.connect() on my table class using the pointer, but when using the arrow keys to navigate the table I can't manage to figure out a way to connect my function. I'm just getting my bearings in pyqt and have tried figuring this out from the docs but it doesn't seem any of the signal methods for QAbstractItemModel work. Not sure if I even tried the right thing. I tried adding a KeyPressEvent definition to my QAbstractTableView class but couldn't get that to work - also tried subclassing QTableView to no avail. Off course not sure any of those attempts were down properly. Here is my basic code that makes a table that highlights rows and prints the value in the first column of the selected row when that row is selected via a pointer click, but if you navigate with the arrow keys obviously nothing prints because the method to print the value isn't called.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractTableModel, QVariant

test_data = [[i,j,k] for i in range(2) for j in range(2) for k in range(2)]

class TableStaticModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, header, data):
        super(TableStaticModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data
        self.header = header

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role==Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
    
        if role==Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
            return Qt.AlignCenter
    
    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self,index):
        return len(self._data[0])

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant(self.header[col])
        return QVariant()

        
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        model = TableStaticModel(['A','B','C'],test_data)
        self.table.setModel(model)
        self.table.clicked.connect(self.get_table_row_value)
        self.table.setSelectionBehavior(self.table.SelectRows)
        self.table.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.table.setColumnWidth(0,83)
        self.table.setColumnWidth(1,85)
        self.table.setColumnWidth(2,83)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

    def get_table_row_value(self):
        index=self.table.selectionModel().currentIndex()
        value=index.sibling(index.row(),0).data()
        print(value)

app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window=MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to select one row then you must set the selectionModel to SingleSelection. On the other hand you must use the selectionChanged signal of the selectionModel:

```py
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView(
            selectionBehavior=QtWidgets.QTableView.SelectRows,
            selectionMode=QtWidgets.QTableView.SingleSelection,
        )
        model = TableStaticModel(["A", "B", "C"], test_data)
        self.table.setModel(model)
        self.table.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.get_table_row_value)
        self.table.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.table.setColumnWidth(0, 83)
        self.table.setColumnWidth(1, 85)
        self.table.setColumnWidth(2, 83)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

    def get_table_row_value(self):
        rows = set()
        for index in self.table.selectedIndexes():
            rows.add(index.row())
        for row in rows:
            ix = self.table.model().index(row, 0)
            print(ix.data())
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works great!  This really helps me see things a bit more clearly.  Why did you implement get_table_row_value the way you did?